# Safari 9: Web inspector highlights every event

Tags: macos, events, safari, web-inspector

that's somewhat embarrassing, but I seem to have changed something in my inspector in Safari 9/El Capitan. Each event, be it browser resizing or CSS transitions, is highlighted red while the event occurs. And I can't find a way to turn it off. Can someone give me a hint? :-)

As far as I understand this should not be a default setting, as one of my Macs has it, the other does not.

Cheers and thanks in advance

Arne

Answer (score 1):

"Fixed" it. In the elements browser, there is a button "Disable colored blinking" (or similar, mine is German "Farbiges Blinken aktivieren/deaktivieren").